# SwiftUI Navigation Bar's localized title not changed

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, navigationbar

I'm facing a problem with Navigation Bar's localized title.

When I change Locale environment object, the navigation bar title of **non-root view** of navigation stack will not get changed.
Please check images below.

`Services` is root view of navigation stack, `Card Maker` is pushed to stack from `Services` view.

`en` locale

[image]

`jp` locale

[image]

Code I've tried

`Services` View

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        NavigationLink {
            CardsMakerView()
        } label: {
            Text("Open Cards")
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Services")
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)   
}
.environment(\.locale, viewModel.language)
```

This is implementation of `CardsMakerView`

```
ScrollView { // ... }
.navigationTitle("Card Maker")
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
```

The `ServiceView` navigation bar title has no problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to put `.navigationTitle("Services")` and other `NavigationView` related modifiers *inside*(!) `NavigationView`.

Comment: you could try using: `.navigationTitle(LocalizedStringKey("Card Maker"))`

Comment: thanks @Asperi @workingdog, i've edited my question and also tried with  `LocalizedStringKey` but no luck. "Card Maker" and "Services" strings are already exist in my Localizable.strings for both languages.

Comment: You can try: 1. .navigationBarTitle(Text(NSLocalizedString("Card Maker", comment: "Card Maker"))) (usually works) 2. use "key style" (what does it mean - in your "Localizable" use one key for strings, in your case "card_maker" = "Card Maker"; and for another language "card_maker" = "";). Hence in call you use something like "Text("card_maker")"

Comment: @ViktorGolubenkov, thanks for comment. I use first language as key. The problem is not about loading localized string. Just guess modifie `.environment(.locale` of swiftui still not work instantly with second view in navigation stack.

Comment: not sure if this is related, but what does `viewModel.language` return, is it `jp` or `ja` ?

Comment: @workingdog it's Locale object, from identifier `ja` or `en`